# How to make textboxes readonly based on drop down selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following scripts that it puts the data-length and data-width on textbox based on drop down question

My question is how I make the `.width` and `.length` textboxes readonly based on dropodown selection as below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.cargo_type').change(function() {
        var eur1width = $('select.cargo_type').find(':selected').data('width');
        $('.width').val(eur1width);

        //make width textbox readonly

        var eur1length = $('select.cargo_type').find(':selected').data('length');
        $('.length').val(eur1length);

        //make length textbox readonly
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set textbox `readonly`.

```
$('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', true);

$('.length').val(eur1length).prop('readonly', true);
```

To remove `readonly` you can set the `readonly` property to false;

```
$('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', false);

$('.length').val(eur1length).prop('readonly', false);
```

**UPDATE**

```
if (eur1width == 'myVal') {
    $('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', true);
} else {
    $('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, how can I turn it to false for any other options?

Comment: I mean, I have other options too, but without any script. If I choose in the beginning the `width` and then change my mind, the textbox will stay as readonly

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Check updated answer, use `if` to check the selected option

Comment: what should i write in myVal ?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos The value, for which you want to make the textbox `readonly`

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop('readonly',true/false);` on the element. Like,

```
if(eur1width == 'checking_val'){
   $('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', true);
}else{
   $('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', false);
}
```

---

### OR

To toggle the property

```
   $('.width').val(eur1width).prop('readonly', !$(this).prop('readonly'));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, how can I turn it to `false` for any other options?

Comment: I mean, I have other options too, but without any script. If I choose in the beginning the width and then change my mind, the textbox will stay as readonly